# how to adjust the date range of choices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

please tell me how to set the range [jqueryUi datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to select year **1950-2014**.

my settings set the range of choice year 2013-2024:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
minDate: "-220",
});
```

I just tried these options:

```
minDate: -2200000,       2004-2024
minDate: -22000,       2004-2024
minDate: -2200000,       2013-2024
minDate: 2200,       2020-2030
minDate: 22000,       2074-2084
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yearRange: '1950:2014',
minDate: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
maxDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1)
```

Note that you can also use `maxDate` to explicitly specify the upper bound.

Comment: @user3607370 I forgot that you also had to set the `yearRange` which specifies what range of values will be shown in the years dropdown.